# extract property of array into new array

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

i try to extract only the properties into an array to create a NSPredicate for this.
is there a shorter way for this than creating a mutable array and looping through all objects?

```
NSMutableArray *extractedIDs = [NSMutableArray array];
for (SomeObject *aObject in self.addedSearchResults) {
    [addedIDs addObject:aObject.someProperty];
}

[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (someOtherProperty IN %@)", addedIDs]
```

can't find something with google (don't really know how to search this problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KVC can help you. Just use:

```
NSArray* extractedIDs = [self.addedSearchResults valueForKey:@"someProperty"];
```

Answer (score 1):

@Mark is right but I think you are looking for:

```
NSArray* extractedIDs = [self.addedSearchResults valueForKeyPath:@"nameOfSomeObject.nameOfSomeProperty"];
```